# How best to store 64MB array in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

I'm modifying a linux kernel module for one time use to aid in recovering a SSD. Essentially I have a virtual image of the SSD, 16 million pages, and I don't know exactly how they fit together, so rather than keep writing out logical images according to the various schemes I come up with (IE as I work out how its storing the translation table), I would prefer to do it dynamically.

There is a module, stackbd, which could be simply modified to permit this mapping of logical block number to the virtual number the virtual image uses. Logical page number is passed through a function which is very easy to modify. If my map of LBN->PPN could be loaded into the module, I could translate one to the other easily.

Question is, I am not a kernel programmer, and my initial idea of keeping a 64MB array in memory seems to be non ideal. So how should I do this? Should I allocate the memory or keep the map in a file which I keep opening, reading the appropriate block numbers from and closing with each request? It does not have to be blazingly fast but not too slow either.

If I should allocate the memory whats the best method, there appear to be more than one. This is a one off, the module will only be loaded while I work on the image, with the possibility of crashing the machine mitigated against, so it does not have to be done the best way, just the quickest way that will work OK.

TIA.

Comment: I'm guessing the most prevalent answer you'll get for this is "don't". That's a  huge amount of data to store in a kernel module. Why are you wanting to do block device forensics in a kernel module, anyway? That just seems like an overall really bad idea (TM)...

Comment: Well thats what I mean. I need to dynamically map 16M addresses which are 4 bytes long, where is the 'proper' way to store this? I'm wondering if the kernel uses another method to do this kind of thing usually.

Comment: `my initial idea of keeping a 64MB array in memory seems to be non ideal.` - Why do you thing so? If you need such array, allocate it. However, you probably cannot allocate such memory at once, __get_free_pages() allows chunks up to 8M or 16M. As for persistent storage, having a file seems the most appropriate for me. But there are other options, of course.

Comment: @Pete, how did you solve your problem? I am interested in knowing it.

Comment: Hi I took Tsyvarevs advise and just did it. Nothing bad has happened and the kernel didn't even complain. On exit the module frees the memory and I guess if you don't do this you would get in trouble quickly if you keep loading the module and unloading it. This is on an 8gb ram machine. I'm not with the code right now but iirc I vmalloced it in the init function. I created a single 64mb array. If you want more details, or details of modifying stackbd, let me know.